Could not register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?
Screenshot of error in the device
Error in the node of terminal was:
ERROR  Warning: Error: Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?
This can also happen if there are multiple copies of '@react-navigation' packages installed.
This error is located at:
in StackNavigator (created by App)
in App
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in TripTracker(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
I tried
I am facing this error. I have tried many solutions which were available on the internet, but they are not working. Here are the solutions I tried:

Clean up node_modules and package-lock.json.
Ensure @react-navigation/native is not installed twice.
Confirm Other Dependencies’ Compatibility.
Use npm dedupe (for npm users).
Reinstall Specific Version of @react-navigation/native

Additionally, I typed this in the terminal: npm ls @react-navigation/native
Result:
@react-navigation/elements@1.3.31
│ │ └── @react-navigation/native@6.1.18 deduped
│ └── @react-navigation/native@6.1.18 deduped
├─┬ @react-navigation/drawer@6.7.2
│ └── @react-navigation/native@6.1.18 deduped
├── @react-navigation/native@6.1.18
└─┬ @react-navigation/stack@6.4.1
└── @react-navigation/native@6.1.18 deduped
App.js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  View,
  Switch,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

import AboutScreen from './components/screens/AboutScreen';
import Stack2Screen from './components/Stack2Screen';
import Stack3Screen from './components/screens/Stack3Screen';
import DrawerFirstScreen from './components/screens/DrawerFirstScreen';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: '--',
});

import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export default function App() {

  function DrawerSecondScreen() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}></View>
    );
  }

  function Stack1Screen() {
    return (
      <Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          drawerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: isEnabled ? 'orange' : 'white',
          },
        }}
        initialRouteName="DrawerFirst" drawerContent={props => {
          return (
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
              <DrawerItemList {...props} />
              <DrawerItem label="Logout" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("SignIn")} />
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
          )
        }}>
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="DrawerFirst"
          component={DrawerFirstScreen}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: isEnabled ? 'white' : 'black',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: isEnabled ? 'black' : 'white',
            },
            headerRight: () => (
              <Switch
                trackColor={{ false: '#767577', true: '#81b0ff' }}
                thumbColor={isEnabled ? '#f5dd4b' : '#f4f3f4'}
                onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                value={isEnabled}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={DrawerSecondScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>

    );
  }

  function HomeScreen() {
    return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Stack1" component={Stack1Screen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Recharge" component={Stack2Screen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Stack3" component={Stack3Screen} />

    </Stack.Navigator>)
  }

  function SettingScreen() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}></View>
    );
  }

  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

  // Set an initializing state whilst Firebase connects
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  // Handle user state changes
  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;

  function SignInScreen() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>SignInScreen</Text>
        <View>
          <Button
            title="Google Sign-In"
            onPress={() => onGoogleButtonPress().then(() => console.log('Signed in with Google!'))}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
  function SignUpScreen() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>SignUpScreen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
  function TabHelperScreen() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="About" component={AboutScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    )
  }
  const authStack = createStackNavigator();

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <authStack.Navigator>
        <authStack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
        <authStack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
      </authStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  const rootStack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <rootStack.Navigator>
        <rootStack.Screen name="TabHelper" component={TabHelperScreen} />
        <rootStack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
        <rootStack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
      </rootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

